# Why Cloudfoundry have dea_logging_agent module?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Why Cloudfoundry have dea_logging_agent module?And it can be run independently?

According to my understanding, dea should use loggregator_emitter LIB to send log and metric to Metron.

Answer (score 0):

The dea_logging_agent ships off the application logs (from each warden container) to loggregator/metron

Comment: Thank you. Dea_logging_agent connect dea's stdout&stderr socket, so dea's log info will redriect to dea_logging_agent.